# convert the unicode in a String into char

Tags: java, string, unicode

This is a basic question and yet I could not find an exact duplicate on SA:

I have this string:

```
String s = "surname\":\"B\\u00f6rner\"},{\"forename\""
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
String s = "surname\":\"Börner\"},{\"forename\""
```

Any way to do this in Java? Thx!

Comment: remove the first backslash, to make it `\u`: `String s = "surname\":\"B\u00f6rner\"},{\"forename\""`

Comment: @Esailija the double backslash is part of the string as I receive it from an API call. Why should I remove it?

Comment: Because it's escaping the unicode escape sequence, making it come out literally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the backslash manually will make Java interpret the unicode as such. If you are unable to modify the string that you receive from the API call, you can use:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\u00f6", "\u00f6");
```

Comment: I think you mean: s.replaceAll("\\\\u00f6", "\\u00f6"). Yet, when I do this replaceAll and then do system.out.println(s) I get:"surname":"Bu00f6rner"},{"forename"

Comment: No, otherwise you will end up with the same result. Dont forget to use the newly build string - Ive updated above.

Comment: ok! Indeed. This question is answered then, but I was actually looking  for a way to detect all unicode encodings (not just \\u00f6) and convert all of them in chars. For clarity, I'll open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "surname\":\"B\u00f6rner\"},{\"forename\"" ;
    try {
        String t = URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8") ;
        System.out.println(t) ;
    }
    catch( Throwable t ) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.err) ;
    }
```

Output: `surname":"Börner"},{"forename"`

You have to find a way to remove extra \ though as others say.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be very difficult as long as you don't need the characters outside the Unicode base plane:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(.{4})").matcher(
    "surname\":\"B\\u00f6rner\"},{\"forename\"");
final StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find())
  m.appendReplacement(b, String.valueOf(((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16))));
m.appendTail(b);
System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is Java source code, then the two string literals mean EXACTLY the same thing ... provided that (in the latter case) you tell the Java compiler what character set the source file is encoded in.  Alternatively, the [`nativetoascii`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) command (with the `-reverse` command) can be used to convert `\uxxxx` unicode escapes in a file to native characters.

If those string values are actually String values, not String literals, then you will need to do some kind of runtime conversion.  (I'm sure that there is a 3rd party library method to do this ...)